# IceMobile - Can I specify a file location to save pictures taken with the camera

Tags: android, icefaces

I've been looking over the API for the camera in IceMobile and it seems the only thing you can do with the picture after taking one is to upload it?

I need to be able to save the pictures to a specific location on the device(It's not just a phone) with certain names and was hoping I could integrate my current JSF application and add the camera component to the page and start taking pictures.

If this does not work I already have an idea of what I'll do to make it work as a native app, but am really hoping to use IceMobile as the rest of the website could have potential for other ideas in the business mobile app and would like to keep it a single app. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently possible with the ICEmobile API, and the ability for the web application to save a file to an arbitrary location on the device is potentially a security issue.  So, it would be necessary to define a restricted, secure version of this feature for it to be added to ICEmobile open source (such as either allowing the user to browse to the location, or specifying the save location to be a well-known location for photos).

Since this is a feature request and does not have an "answer", please contact product.support@icesoft.com or post on the ICEmobile forums to discuss further.  Once that discussion is complete, the final result can be posted here as an answer.